# Const declaration curiosity

Tags: c++, constants

Ok, so i'm doing some exercise from a book, and I saw this declaration

```
float f, const c =9.9;
```

Initially, I thought this would be a compiler error, but I went into VS2013 and tested this, and it did not throw an error. I could even modify the c variable after declaration. I would like to know why and how is this possible,what is the compiler even doing with the const keyword in this case?

Comment: Don't start reading the book from the exercises.

Comment: That does not work with clang and gcc.

Comment: `int main() { float f, const c =9.9; }` does not compile with GCC 4.9.2 with `-std=c++11`

Comment: What book are you reading? When is it from? This seems like something from C in the pre-standard times.

Comment: Looks like another microsoft's parallel universe's issues.

Comment: The Visual C's `cl` command from Visual Studio 2010 says `warning C4228: nonstandard extension used : qualifiers after comma in declarator list are ignored` which explains why you can modify c and why it doesn't work on gcc/clang

Comment: Please name the book.

Comment: I'm sorry @VictorPolevoy, I forgot to say, this book has only exercises, no theory.

Comment: @Rndp13 It's called C++ Secrets, by Constantin Galatan, a romanian exercise book.

Comment: You better burn the book and instead pick one from [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: @RedX well, I would gladly, but I have an exam in OOP and these exercises are similar to the ones I get in the exam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to know why and how is this possible,what is the compiler even doing with the const keyword in this case?

It's not compiling it. Not with [C++14](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e797afcbd9d48497), nor [C++11](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/10ccf7f73c342304), nor [C++03](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fcffbcd33a9fac74), not even [C](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0e70574eb403be96).